# c# stop code execution within library

Tags: c#, php, winforms

I'm trying to figure out in C# Winforms if is anywhere possible to stop code execution by calling a function and not a `return`.

The following code is possible in PHP

```
if($something == null)
   $this->response->error(0);

// This code is never executed if the condition is true
echo 'Hello';
```

And the library `response`, has something like:

```
public class Response
{
   public function error($index)
   {
     $response = array();

     switch ($index)
     {
        case 0: $response = array('msg' => 'fields missing..'); break;
     }

     // The trick is here
     exit(json_encode($response));
   }
}
```

So, in the C# project and within my form I call the `response` library this way:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    libraries.Response Response = new libraries.Response();

    if(textBox1.Text == "")
        Response.error(0);

    // The code continues to get executed even if the condition is true
    button2.PerformClick();
}
```

The response triggers an `MessageBox` which obviously has nothing that make code execution to stop.

```
class Response
{
    public void error(int index)
    { 
        string msg = "";

        switch (index) 
        {
            case 0: msg = "Fields missing.."; break;
        }

        MessageBox.Show(msg, "My app", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
    }
}
```

Now, I know that I can use the `return` as the below code shows to stop code execution, but I was wondering if there's something else that I can put in the library `response`that would do the trick?

```
if(textBox1.Text == "")
{
   Response.error(0);
   return;
}
```

Comment: Is the libraries code running asynchronously in a background worker or task? If its in a background worker you can subscribe the worker to an event and hook into that to kill it off. If its running on the same thread then the code thread will be locked up until the library returns anyway.

Comment: In .NET  to stop execution of code in exceptional states, you can throw an exception. This way the lines of code which are after throw statement will not execute and the exception will bubble up until the first try/catch block and code of catch block will execute.

Answer (score 1):

In .NET  to stop execution of code in exceptional situations, you can throw an exception. This way the lines of code which are after throw statement will not execute and the exception will bubble up the stack until the first [`try-catch`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0yd65esw.aspx) which matches with the specific exception type and code of the catch block will execute. If no suitable try-catch block found in the call stack, the process will be terminated and a message will be displayed to the user.

> Exceptions should not be used to change the flow of a program as part
>   of ordinary execution. Exceptions should only be used to report and
>   handle error conditions.

To throw an [`Exception`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.exception(v=vs.110).aspx) you can use [`throw`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1ah5wsex.aspx) statement. For example:

```
public string GetObjectTypeName(object something)
{
    if(something==null)
        throw new Exception("Some Exception Message");

    return something.GetType().Name;
}
```

For more information take a look at these resources:

- [Exceptions and Exception Handling](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173160.aspx)
- [Creating and Throwing Exceptions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173163.aspx)
- [Framework Design Guidelines → Design Guidelines for Exceptions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229014(v=vs.110).aspx)
- [Best Practices for Exceptions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/seyhszts(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Exception isn't the answer because I want to use a `MessageBox`, otherwise the UI of Exception will scare the living shit out of the user. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Don't show a scary exception UI! You can handle `Exception` using `try-catch` blocks and show a `MessageBox` or log the error or hide it from user or perform some other recovery task. Also `Application.ThreadException ` or `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException` events are some other useful things that you should know more about them. I believe using `Exceptions` is the way you should go :) Take a look at those useful links which I posted in answer.

Comment: The goal is to have two lines of code 1. the condition, 2. the response. Of course I know that I can use a Try Catch block, a return or a else condition, but that isn't my goal.

Comment: Showing a `MessageBox` doesn't make sense in a code library like data access layer, business logic and so on. Exception throwing/handling is the only solution for the problem in C# world :)

Comment: Let me know if you have any other question about the answer or if you find it useful :)

Answer (score 0):

Also you can use `else` clause:

```
if(textBox1.Text == "")
{
   Response.error(0);
}
else
{
    button2.PerformClick();
}
```

but if you are not throwing an error, using `goto` statement and don't want to use a lot if-elses then `return` is your option.

**EDIT**

The only option to make the caller method to stop executing from the called method I can think of(except fully shutting down your app) is to throw an `Exception`.